# Join returns too much info

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables

```
Table1
+---------+--------+-------+----+
| CALDATE | GROOMS | ROOMS | fn |
+---------+--------+-------+----+
| 1/5/18  |     15 |    17 | A12|
| 1/5/18  |      0 |     0 | A12|
| 1/6/18  |      0 |     0 | B34|
| 1/6/18  |     75 |    77 | B34|
| 1/7/18  |    123 |   125 | C56|
| 1/7/18  |      0 |     0 | C56|
+---------+--------+-------+----+
```

-

```
Table2
+----------+--------+----+
| ROOMDATE | pickup | FN |
+----------+--------+----+
| 1/5/18   |      0 | A12|
| 1/5/18   |      2 | A12|
| 1/5/18   |      1 | A12|
| 1/5/18   |      7 | A12|
| 1/6/18   |      2 | B34|
| 1/6/18   |      1 | B34|
| 1/6/18   |     13 | B34|
| 1/7/18   |      3 | C56|
| 1/7/18   |      0 | C56|
| 1/7/18   |     12 | C56|
+----------+--------+----+
```

Querying each I use

```
Select caldate as date, sum(grooms) as g, sum (rooms) as r
from Table1
```

and

```
Select roomdate as date, sum(pickup) as p
from Table2
```

These each give me the info I'm expecting, however when I try and join them things get wonky. I was hoping for something like

```
Select caldate as date,
sum(grooms) as g,
sum(rooms) as r,
sum(pickup) as p
from Table1
inner join table2 on table1.fn = table2.fn
```

But that returns way too high of each.

How do I join these queries so that I get my expected output of

```
+--------+-----+-----+----+----+
|  Date  |  g  |  r  | p  | fn |
+--------+-----+-----+----+----+
| 1/5/18 |  15 |  17 | 10 | A12|
| 1/6/18 |  75 |  77 | 16 | B34|
| 1/7/18 | 123 | 125 | 15 | C56|
+--------+-----+-----+----+----+
```

Comment: That syntax with SUM() without GROUP BY that give you info you are expecting is invalid in tsql. Are you sure you have tagged correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each row in your first table will match with each available row in the other table based on your join predicate. Take `fn = A12` for example: since you have 2 rows in table1 and 4 rows in table2, you will end up with (4x2) 8 rows in your result set.  That will cause your sums to be higher than they should be.

One way to fix this is to use derived tables to get your sums, then join them together:

```
SELECT t1.date, g, r, p, t1.fn
FROM (SELECT fn, caldate as date, sum(grooms) as g, sum (rooms) as r
      FROM Table1
      GROUP BY fn, caldate) t1
JOIN (SELECT fn, roomdate as date, sum(pickup) as p
      FROM Table2
      GROUP BY fn, roomdate) t2 on t1.fn = t2.fn
```

This makes sure there is one row returned from each table before the join.

Comment: This works with the sample data, but won't work if there are multiple roomdate values for the same FN in table 2. Since you're not joining on roomdate, I don't think it should be included in the group by of the 2nd query.

Comment: @MaxSzczurek Can only work off of the sample data we're given... and I left `roomdate` in so OP can run each query independently if they wish - I think it helps understand the idea of derived tables... but you're right, it's not required for the end result.

Comment: Yeah, but if you change the roomdate value in the last row of the sample data for table 2, you get a duplicate row values from table 1 in the result set, so I don't think it's just redundant - I think it's logically incorrect. I'm updating my answer, because the sample data is insufficient for us to ascertain exactly what problem the poster is trying to solve.

Comment: @MaxSzczurek I appreciate your tenacity but I wouldn't worry about it too much.  If your answer fits the sample data without any major assumptions then you have a good answer (you do).  Let OP correct their data if it's a bad representation.

Comment: One aspect of finding the answer to a question is finding shortcomings in the sample data that allow for oversights. Basic QA. I think any other approach is lazy.

Comment: I thought I was showing multiple roomdate values for the same fin in table 2??

Comment: @gilliduck Nah, they are all the same in the sample data.

Comment: Other good answers, but giving it to this one due to the added explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You should be Grouping by 'caldate'. This way you will only be getting the sums per date.

```
Select caldate as date,
sum(grooms) as g,
sum(rooms) as r,
sum(pickup) as p
from Table1
inner join table2 on table1.fn = table2.fn
group by caldate
```

Comment: I was, I forgot that in the example

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that allows you to group by FN and date:

```
select format(caldate, 'M/d/yyyy') as date, sum(grooms) as g, sum(rooms) as r, t2.p, t1.fn
from Table1 t1
inner join (
    select fn, roomdate, sum(pickup) as p from Table2 group by fn, roomdate
    )t2 on t1.fn = t2.fn and t1.caldate = t2.roomdate
group by t1.caldate, t1.fn, t2.p
```

I created some sample data with DML statements so you can test grouping by different combinations of FN and date, and the output:

```
declare @t1 table (caldate datetime, grooms int, rooms int, fn varchar(3))
declare @t2 table (roomdate datetime, pickup int, fn varchar(3))

insert into @t1 select '1/5/18', 15, 17,'A12'
insert into @t1 select '1/5/18',  0,  0,'A12'
insert into @t1 select '1/6/18',  0,  0,'B34'
insert into @t1 select '1/6/18', 75, 77,'B34'
insert into @t1 select '1/7/18',123,125,'C56'
insert into @t1 select '1/8/18',100,200,'C56' -- changed to 1/8/18, changed vals

insert into @t2 select '1/5/18', 0 ,'A12'
insert into @t2 select '1/5/18', 2 ,'A12'
insert into @t2 select '1/5/18', 1 ,'A12'
insert into @t2 select '1/5/18', 7 ,'A12'
insert into @t2 select '1/6/18', 2 ,'B34'
insert into @t2 select '1/6/18', 1 ,'B34'
insert into @t2 select '1/6/18',13 ,'B34'
insert into @t2 select '1/7/18', 3 ,'C56'
insert into @t2 select '1/7/18', 0 ,'C56'
insert into @t2 select '1/8/18',12 ,'C56' -- changed to 1/8/18

select format(caldate, 'M/d/yyyy') as date, sum(grooms) as g, sum(rooms) as r, t2.p, t1.fn
from @t1 t1
inner join (
    select fn, roomdate, sum(pickup) as p from @t2 group by fn, roomdate
    )t2 on t1.fn = t2.fn and t1.caldate = t2.roomdate
group by t1.caldate, t1.fn, t2.p
```

Output:

```
date        g       r       p       fn
1/5/2018    15      17      10      A12
1/6/2018    75      77      16      B34
1/7/2018    123     125     3       C56
1/8/2018    100     200     12      C56
```

If you don't also join by date, then adding different combinations of caldate/fn give you duplicates. You must mean to join by the date as well, right?

Comment: Joining by date is definitely needed.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you get more rows than expected is because of join condition. if you want to find grooms and rooms for each fn on each day you have add date to join condition as well:

```
Select table1.caldate as date,
  sum(grooms) as g,
  sum(rooms) as r,
  sum(pickup) as p
  from table1
  inner join table2 on  table1.fn      = table2.fn
                    and table1.caldate = table2.roomdate
```

Comment: The problem with this is if there's two rows in table1 and two rows in table2 for the same `fn` and date, you'll still multiply rows.  The example data always has 0s in one of the two records so it will appear to work, but we don't know if that's always the case.

Comment: Tried that, still to much info, like Bacon Bits said